# Animate the activity entry

Tags: android, android-activity, jquery-animate

I need to start an activity  in an animated way..can anyone help me?
Creating an intent and starting an activity in normal way will show new activity.I need to start it from one side,say left side..how to animate it near creating intent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidein_left, R.anim.slideout_right);
```

Where R.anim.* are Animation XML files in your /res/anim/ folder.

The following is an example of my `slidein_left`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

And `slideout_right`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

What this will do is slide both activities to the left, making the new activity slide in from the left, pushing the old activity out to the right.

Also, as stated by @njzk2, please attempt to make an effort yourself before asking questions, and provide us with things that you may have already tried.